# Custom permission error 309004/309005

Tags: permissions, authorization

I'm trying to create a custom permission and push an action on my contract, but experience problems with authorization. Alice.acc is the account where the contract is set to. Giveprm is the custom permission level. The two versions I have tried are:

```
require_auth2(permission_level{N(alice.acc),N(giveprm) });
```

and

```
require_auth(permission_level{N(alice.acc),N(giveprm)});
```

When trying to access function increment, which takes no arguments, I wish to use account alice@active, so I have permissions on account alice.acc as this:

```
cleos get account alice.acc 
privileged: false
permissions: 
 owner     1:    1 EOS77dNi2z2nSrwuVrdGX7QHPyohfHwLeSeZo8CbU3yZKWarbHTSv
    active     2:    2 alice@active, 1 bob@active, 
       giveprm     2:    2 alice@active, 1 bob@active,
```

Calling the function like:

```
  cleos push action alice.acc increment '""' --permission alice@active
```

But I'm getting error

```
 Error 3090004: missing required authority
 Ensure that you have the related authority inside your transaction!;
 If you are currently using 'cleos push action' command, try to add the     relevant authority using -p option.
 Error Details:
 missing authority of alice.acc/giveprm
```

Am I using require_auth in an incorrect way, or is there a problem with the permissions on the account?
Thank you!

Comment: Try alice@owner a go instead, might not be able to add such a permission with only the active permission.

Comment: @JohnWilliamson This shouldn't be an issue with permission level between active and owner - since it's not changing any permission levels. What I'm specifically trying to do is to use a restricted permission (my maybe not so adequately named) giveprm to access this function, but can't figure out how that's done.

Answer (score 1):

For every transaction, we need to have at least one signer to bill the net and cpu.

And unless we link the action with alice@active permission, the minimum required authority is active.

Try the following command:

`cleos set action permission alice.cc alice.cc increament alice@active`